# Format date in Angular 2

Tags: angular, typescript

I am using Angular2(typescript), I have a problem with type Date:

I get a String e.g " `26/06/2018` " I need convert this String in other String `2018-06-26T00:00:00+01:00`

I tried with :

```
 let dateStart : any ;

  if (filterDateStart != undefined) {
      console.log('before' , filterDateStart);
      dateStart = new Date(filterDateStart).toLocaleTimeString();
      console.log('After' , dateStart); --->  ƒ toLocaleTimeString() { [native code] }
  }
```

or   `dateStart = new Date(filterDateStart).toLocaleDateString();` I don't get format `26T00:00:00+01:00`

How I can resolve this ? Thanks.

**Update :**

I tried with :

```
  dateStart = new Date(filterDateStart.split('/').reverse().join('/'));
  dateStart = new Date(filterDateEnd).toLocaleDateString();
  dateStart =  new Date(filterDateStart).toISOString();
  dateStart = new Date(filterDateStart.split('/').reverse().toISOString('/'));
```

Comment: at now what your are getting result??

Comment: I am using .toLocaleDateString(); but I need " 26T00:00:00+01:00 "

Comment: is this a ISO date format? or what?

Comment: I don´t know this format, sorry.

Answer (score 0):

The Date '26/06/2018' isn't parseable, but '06/26/2018' is.

After that, you forgot the `()` after `toLocalTimeString`;

```
let dateStart = new Date('06/26/2018').toLocaleTimeString();
```

returnes a formated string.

Comment: dateStart =  new Date(filterDateStart).toLocaleTimeString(); I get --> 0:00:00

Answer (score 0):

You can do by following way

```js
var origDate = "26/06/2018"

var newDate = new Date(origDate.split('/').reverse().join('/'));

console.log(newDate);
```

Comment: I get : Tue Jun 26 2018 00:00:00 GMT+0200 (hora de verano de Europa central)

Comment: New Date will  give your browser system stranded time for me it's give `Tue Jun 26 2018 00:00:00 GMT+0530 (IST)` but after you can convert date to any timezone as you want. This article explain you how to convert timezone https://www.techrepublic.com/article/convert-the-local-time-to-another-time-zone-with-this-javascript/.

Answer (score 0):

Use momenjs pass your date(26/06/2018) into this function you wil
    get the 2016-06-26T00:00:00+01:00 format date.

```
public static FormatDate(d: string) {
    return  moment(d, 'DD/MM/YYYY');
}
```

I hope this is helpfull.

Answer (score 0):

Vanilla JS

```js
const date = new Date(...'26/06/2018'.split('/').reverse()).toISOString();

console.log(date);
```

Explanation

```
'26/06/2018'.split('/')
> ['26', '06', '2018'].reverse()
> ...['2018', '06', '26']
> new Date('2018', '06', '26')
> Thu Jul 26 2018 00:00:00 Date object call toISOString()
```

Comment: dateStart = new Date(filterDateStart.split('/').reverse().toISOString('/'));

Comment: Method Split can't use with String, and ToIOString  can't use with Date ... and you use all in the same line..

Comment: @EduBw Why? `split` can be called on `string` and `toISOString` can be called on `Date`.

Answer (score 0):

Use regex to convert format and then create date object

```
new Date("26/06/2018".replace( /(\d{2})\/(\d{2})\/(\d{4})/, "$2/$1/$3"))
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use a library like moment.js:
http://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/

The following will output your desired format.

```
var date = '26/06/2018';
var dateObj = moment(date, "DD/MM/YYYY").toDate();
alert(moment(dateObj).format("YYYY/MM/DDTHH:mm:ssZ"));
```

Output: http://jsfiddle.net/rLjQx/65986/